# Magento 2 Database table not creating

Tags: magento2, php, module, database

I'm trying to add a custom table for a module. The following code sits the Setup folder of my module:

```
<?php

namespace tivol\storeAvailability\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $installer = $setup;
    $installer->startSetup();

    // Get tivol_storeavailability table
    $tableName = $installer->getTable('tivol_storeavailability');
    // Check if the table already exists
    if ($installer->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) != true) {
        // Create tivol_storeavailability table
        $table = $installer->getConnection()
            ->newTable($tableName)
                        ->addColumn(
                            'id',
                            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                            null,
                            ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
                            'Id'
                        )
                        ->addColumn(
                            'label',
                            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                            null,
                            ['default' => null, 'nullable' => false],
                            'Name'
                        )
                        ->addColumn(
                            'value',
                            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                            null,
                            ['default' => null, 'nullable' => false],
                            'Stores'
                        );
            ->setComment('News Table')
            ->setOption('type', 'InnoDB')
            ->setOption('charset', 'utf8');
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
    }

    $installer->endSetup();
}
}
```

when I run it I get the following error on the frontend:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'magento.tivol_storeavailability' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT
>   `main_table`.* FROM `tivol_storeavailability` AS `main_table`

Any ideas as to why the table is not being created

Comment: you have to first delete your module entry from setup_module table and try again.

Comment: you are inserting `$installer->getTable('tivol_storeavailability')` inside of `isTableExist`, try changing `$tableName` to `$tableName = 'tivol_storeavailability';`